# iOS10 plain UITableView will not pull down anymore

Tags: uitableview, ios10, uirefreshcontrol

Since ios10, my plain UITableView will not pull down anymore, unless the UITableView has enough rows to extend beyond the bottom of the screen.  I have a UIRefreshControl on the UITableView, so I need to be able to pull the UITableView down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, in case anyone else runs into this.  As of iOS10, you need to explicitly set Bounce Vertical to true.

Objective-C

```
[self.tableView setAlwaysBounceVertical:YES];
```

Swift

```
tableView.alwaysBounceVertical = true
```

Storyboard

[image]